# What is the minimal value of $a$ that will give me the greater result?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$(a+\frac{1}{8})^0*n$ $+$ $(a+\frac{1}{8})^1*n$ $+$$(a+\frac{1}{8})^2*n$ $+$ $(a+\frac{1}{8})^3*n$ + ... $+$ $(a+\frac{1}{8})^{log_8(n)}*n$

What is the minimal value of $a$ that will give me the greater result ?

I noticed that if $a=\frac{7}{8}$ then I can get $nlog(n)$.

I can use a hint.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Simplify by $x=a+\frac{1}{8}$ to get $f_n(x)=n\sum_{k=0}^b x^k +nx^{log_8(n)}=\frac{1-x^{b+1}}{1-x}+nx^{log_8(n)}$ where $b=$ integer $\le log_8(n)$.

Set $f'_n(x)=0$ to find min for $x$.

Comment: I followed your hint and found the derivative. But it seems that it is too complicated to continue.

Comment: Try to get an answer omitting the $x^{log_8(n)}$ term.